# connect to ad-hoc wireless network using c#

Tags: c#, wireless, adhoc

How can I connect to ad-hoc wireless network using c# I tried using wlanApi class but failed to get it correct profile xaml ?

Comment: Have you tried using this bit of code:  http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/  I've never used it myself, but a friend of mine has.

Comment: yes I tried but can't connect to ad-hoc if your friend can please ask him howa thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem you face while trying to connect?

just create the profile and use WlanSetProfile followed by WlanConnect

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706795(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx